# Adding a CAShapeLayer goes out of bounds swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, cashapelayer

I'm trying to add a dark view to my previewLayer except my rectOfInterest, here is my code. videoPreviewLayer is my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and qrCodeFrameView is my rectOfInterest

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
        qrCodeView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        path.addRect(videoPreviewLayer!.bounds)
        path.addRect(qrCodeFrameView.frame)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

        videoPreviewLayer?.addSublayer(maskLayer)
```

[image]

but I get this how can I make the rect stay in bound?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark. But most likely the problem is that your views change position while your code for adding mask does not.

Assuming that you currently have the following code:

```
func applyMask() {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    qrCodeView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    path.addRect(videoPreviewLayer!.bounds)
    path.addRect(qrCodeFrameView.frame)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
    maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

    videoPreviewLayer?.addSublayer(maskLayer) 
}

func viewDidLoadOrSomeOtherInitKindOfMethod() {
    applyMask()
}
```

Then you need to just upgrade to

```
let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer?

func applyMask() {
    self.maskLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    qrCodeView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    path.addRect(videoPreviewLayer!.bounds)
    path.addRect(qrCodeFrameView.frame)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
    maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

    videoPreviewLayer?.addSublayer(maskLayer) 
    
    self.maskLayer = maskLayer
}

// Relevant if doing this in view controller:
open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    applyMask()
}

// Relevant if doing this in UIView using auto-layout
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    applyMask()
}
    
// Relevant if doing this in UIView using manual setting of frame
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        applyMask()
    }
}
```

The key here is to recreate the mask every time your views change position. The mask needs to be preserved and removed before it is recreated. Then simply call the mask applying in methods that change your view sizes.

Comment: Thank you. calling applyMask() in viewDidLayoutSubviews worked

Comment: I upvoted but my reputation is low so did not affect the voting score. A follow up is now those four lines is a CAShapeLayer drawn and added as a sublayer to qrCodeFrameView. So instead of `path.addRect(qrCodeFrameView.frame)` in `applyMask()` how can I make it stay within the bounds of the CAShapeLayer

Comment: @eloka Not sure I understand what you mean in followup.

Comment: So what I failed to mention was it was going beyond `qrCodeFrameView` also, applying your solution makes it stay in `qrCodeFrameView` bounds but it still goes beyond the frame of the CAShapeLayer which is a sublayer of `qrCodeFrameView`, so instead of adding qrCodeFrameView.frame to the path in applyMaskhow can add the CAShapeLayer created

Comment: @eloka I think I understand. You want the visible part within those white lines while it goes beyond them, right? For that we would need to see more code. But if those lines are of fixed thickness and position then you can simply use `qrCodeFrameView.frame.insetBy(dx: 12, dy: 12)` to inset your frame. Replace `12` with whatever the values should be...

Comment: I already position the white lines to be just outside qrCodeFrameView enclosing it, so I'm good. Thanks for your help